# Multi level nested menu from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I create a nested menu (with "sub-sub-sub...-n") items from my JSON, based on the "id" and the "pid"?

Code details:

```
id - item ID
lvl - level of the item
pid - parent ID of the item
pos - position of the item
nm - name of the item
```

JSON:

```
[{"id":1,"lvl":0,"pid":0,"pos":0,"nm":"HomeTree"},
{"id":5,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":0,"nm":"Books"},
{"id":2,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":1,"nm":"Jobs"},
{"id":16,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":2,"nm":"Music"},
{"id":17,"lvl":2,"pid":16,"pos":0,"nm":"Relax Sets"},
{"id":12,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":3,"nm":"Cars"},
{"id":13,"lvl":2,"pid":12,"pos":0,"nm":"BMW"},
{"id":14,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":4,"nm":"Web"},
{"id":15,"lvl":2,"pid":14,"pos":0,"nm":"PHP Analytics"},
{"id":18,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":5,"nm":"Hardware"},
{"id":19,"lvl":2,"pid":18,"pos":0,"nm":"EVGA SR2 Upgrades"},
{"id":31,"lvl":2,"pid":18,"pos":1,"nm":"Keyboards"},
{"id":20,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":6,"nm":"Movies"},
{"id":21,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":7,"nm":"Games"},
{"id":22,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":8,"nm":"Robots"},
{"id":25,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":9,"nm":"Magazines"},
{"id":26,"lvl":2,"pid":25,"pos":0,"nm":"IT Security"},
{"id":27,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":10,"nm":"Management"},
{"id":28,"lvl":2,"pid":27,"pos":0,"nm":"Holacracy"},
{"id":29,"lvl":3,"pid":28,"pos":0,"nm":"Testtt"}]
```

What I need:

```
HomeTree
    Books
    Jobs
    Music
    Relax Sets
    Cars
        BMW
    Web
        PHP Analytics
    Hardware
        EVGA SR2 Upgrades
    Keyboards
    Movies
    Games
    Robots
    Magazines
        IT Security
    Management
        Holacracy
            Testtt
```

My current code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: './jstree_head.php?operation=full_tree',
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
        var output="<br />";
        for (var i in data)
        {
                var rid = data[i].id;
                var rpid = data[i].pid;
                var rlvl = data[i].lvl;
                var rnm = data[i].nm;

                var nest = '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;';
                if(rpid > 1) {
                                 nm = nest+rnm+'<br>';
                             }
                else {nm = rnm+'<br>';}

            output+='' + nm + '';
        }
        $('#content').html(output);
    }
});
```

Right now I can't account for deep sub-sub levels, what is the right way to do that?

--- UPDATE ---

What I tried is:

```
var nest = '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;';
if(rpid > 1) {
    nm = nest+rnm+'<br>';
}
else {nm = rnm+'<br>';}

output+='' + nm + '';
```

But this does only one level of parent items.

Comment: In my current code: `                var nest = '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;';
                if(rpid > 1) {
                                 nm = nest+rnm+'<br>';
                             }
                else {nm = rnm+'<br>';}

            output+='' + nm + '';`

Comment: Please update your question with your attempt.

Comment: Thanks! I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your output is not formatted, I am first creating a hierarchy of parent-child which is then being used to print the output. Instead of directly storing the values in string, I am using JSON as it's much easier to dynamically add child there.

```
var data = [{"id":1,"lvl":0,"pid":0,"pos":0,"nm":"HomeTree"},
    {"id":5,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":0,"nm":"Books"},
    {"id":2,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":1,"nm":"Jobs"},
    {"id":16,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":2,"nm":"Music"},
    {"id":17,"lvl":2,"pid":16,"pos":0,"nm":"Relax Sets"},
    {"id":12,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":3,"nm":"Cars"},
    {"id":13,"lvl":2,"pid":12,"pos":0,"nm":"BMW"},
    {"id":14,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":4,"nm":"Web"},
    {"id":15,"lvl":2,"pid":14,"pos":0,"nm":"PHP Analytics"},
    {"id":18,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":5,"nm":"Hardware"},
    {"id":19,"lvl":2,"pid":18,"pos":0,"nm":"EVGA SR2 Upgrades"},
    {"id":31,"lvl":2,"pid":18,"pos":1,"nm":"Keyboards"},
    {"id":20,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":6,"nm":"Movies"},
    {"id":21,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":7,"nm":"Games"},
    {"id":22,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":8,"nm":"Robots"},
    {"id":25,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":9,"nm":"Magazines"},
    {"id":26,"lvl":2,"pid":25,"pos":0,"nm":"IT Security"},
    {"id":27,"lvl":1,"pid":1,"pos":10,"nm":"Management"},
    {"id":28,"lvl":2,"pid":27,"pos":0,"nm":"Holacracy"},
    {"id":29,"lvl":3,"pid":28,"pos":0,"nm":"Testtt"}];

var output="<br />";

var res = [];
function createRelationship(){
    for (var i in data)
    {
        if(data[i].pid == 0 && data[i].id == 1){
            res.push({
            id: data[i].id,
            nm: data[i].nm
            });
        }
        else{
            var parent = findParent(data[i].pid, res);
            if(parent){
                if(!parent.items){
                    parent.items = [];
                }
                parent.items.push({
                    id: data[i].id,
                    nm: data[i].nm
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

function findParent(pid, _res){
    if(_res){
        if(_res.id == pid){
            return _res;
        }
        var len = _res.length ? _res.length : _res.items ? _res.items.length : 0;
        for(var i =0; i< len; i++){
            if(_res[i] && _res[i].id == pid){
                return _res[i];
            }
            else{
                var child = _res[i] ? _res[i] : _res;
                if(child){
                    for(var j=0;j<child.items.length;j++){
                        var res = findParent(pid, child.items[j]);
                        if(res){
                            return res;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}



function printOutPut(obj, spaceCount){
    var space = '';
    for(var i = 0; i< spaceCount; i++){
        space+= '&nbsp;';
    }
    output += space + obj.nm;
    output += "<br />";
    if(obj.items){
        for(i = 0; i < obj.items.length; i++){
            printOutPut(obj.items[i], (spaceCount + 4));
        }
    }
}

createRelationship();

for(var z =0; z<res.length;z++){
    printOutPut(res[z], 1);
}

document.write(output);
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect that working with flat array would be so complex to handle :(
That's why I couldn't get it working - the logic is way too complex for me. Thank you P.K. Your help is greatly appreciated. I wouldn't have come up with this complex code.

Comment: Yes, which is why the ideal approach would have been to send the formatted JSON object from the server itself. But, if you don't have any control on the server side code, then you need to format it here on the client-side like this.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is a flat array, as opposed to nested JSON objects, you can't use a recursive function.

Instead, you can loop over all the elements, keeping track of a list parents as the `lvl` attribute changes. As the `lvl` increases, add the previous element to your list of parents and use this latest parent for all following items. As the `lvl` decreases, remove a latest parent from the list and use the one before it in the list instead for all following items.